# Flutter Retrofit upload multipart throws 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: flutter, retrofit, multipart, dio

I'm trying to upload an image using Multipart from Flutter Retrofit using this code

```dart
  @POST("apiUrl/upload/files")
  @MultiPart()
  Future<TSSuccessResponse<UploadFileRemoteResponse>> uploadFile(
      @Part() File file);
```

However it keeps getting error 415 that says application/form-octet is not supported MediaType.

```
E/flutter ( 8367): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 415.
E/flutter ( 8367): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:530:7)
E/flutter ( 8367): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
E/flutter ( 8367): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 8367): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
E/flutter ( 8367): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
E/flutter ( 8367): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
E/flutter ( 8367): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 8367): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23:5)
E/flutter ( 8367): #8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:617:45)
E/flutter ( 8367): #9      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
E/flutter ( 8367): #10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 8367): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
E/flutter ( 8367): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
E/flutter ( 8367): #13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
E/flutter ( 8367): #14     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666:7)
E/flutter ( 8367): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 8367): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)


I/flutter ( 8367): ╔ DioErrorType.badResponse
I/flutter ( 8367): ║    {
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         statusCode: 415,
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         "File type application/octet-stream is not matching: image, pdf, powerpoint, prese
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         ntation, video, video/quicktime"
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         error: "Unsupported Media Type"
I/flutter ( 8367): ║    }
I/flutter ( 8367): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Then I tried to change the request to include content-type in the @Part() tag as someone mentioned, so that it satisfies the generated file from Retrofit.

```dart
  @POST("apiUrl/upload/files")
  @MultiPart()
  Future<TSSuccessResponse<UploadFileRemoteResponse>> uploadFile(
      @Part(contentType: "image/png") File file);
```

But it throw another error, that is

```
E/flutter ( 8367): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 415.
E/flutter ( 8367): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:530:7)
E/flutter ( 8367): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
E/flutter ( 8367): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 8367): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
E/flutter ( 8367): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
E/flutter ( 8367): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
E/flutter ( 8367): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 8367): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23:5)
E/flutter ( 8367): #8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:617:45)
E/flutter ( 8367): #9      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
E/flutter ( 8367): #10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 8367): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
E/flutter ( 8367): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
E/flutter ( 8367): #13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
E/flutter ( 8367): #14     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666:7)
E/flutter ( 8367): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 8367): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)


I/flutter ( 8367): ╔ DioErrorType.badResponse
I/flutter ( 8367): ║    {
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         statusCode: 415,
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         message: "File type is not matching",
I/flutter ( 8367): ║         error: "Unsupported Media Type"
I/flutter ( 8367): ║    }
I/flutter ( 8367):
```

I also tried chaging the contentType to "image/*" but it throws error on the MediaType.parser (from the generated file) saying that it's an invalid type.

Is there anything I'm missing in this scenario? Have anyone solved this problem before? I tried solutions mentioned by [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509972/flutter-dio-how-to-upload-image),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60594063/flutter-dio-upload-files-pdf-docs) and many others but still stuck in this problem. Thx in advance.

**One thing to note: This request works normally in Postman with the same file.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem. Someone has raised this issue in [github](https://github.com/cfug/dio/issues/250), and apparently the root cause problem is Dio set the MediaType to `application/octet-stream` when we don't specify any.

And if we specify it from retrofit like this (through contentType of the @Part),

```dart
  @POST("apiUrl/upload/files")
  @MultiPart()
  Future<TSSuccessResponse<UploadFileRemoteResponse>> uploadFile(
      @Part(contentType: "image/jpg") File file);
```

the following line in the generated files from Retrofit will still throw an Error since it doesn't match the pattern.

```
MediaType.parse(contentType)
```

My solution is to use the normal Dio request then specify the mime type using [mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) package from pub.dev as per suggested from the preceeding github links.

```dart
    import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: fileName,
          contentType: MediaType.parse("${lookupMimeType(fileName)}")),
    });

    final response = await dio.post(
      "api/uploadFile",
      data: data,
      options: Options(headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by parsing Files into MultipartFiles and dynamically setting their contentType. I used [mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) library to determine the contentType of the file.

Method for parsing Files into MultipartFiles:

```
Future<List<MultipartFile>> filesToMultipartFiles(List<File> files) async {
  final multipartFiles = <MultipartFile>[];

  for (final file in files) {
    final filename = file.path.split('/').last;
    final fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();

    List<int> header = [];
    for (var element in fileBytes) {
      if (element == 0) continue;
      header.add(element);
    }

    final mime = lookupMimeType(filename, headerBytes: header) ?? '';
    final mimeParts = mime.split('/');

    if (mimeParts.length != 2) throw Exception('Invalid file type');

    final multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      fileBytes,
      filename: file.path.split('/').last,
      contentType: MediaType(mimeParts[0], mimeParts[1]),
    );
    multipartFiles.add(multipartFile);
  }

  return multipartFiles;
}
```

API class:

```
@RestApi()
abstract class _FilesAPI {
  factory _FilesAPI(Dio dio) = __FilesAPI;

  @POST('/files')
  @MultiPart()
  Future<List<AppFile>> _uploadFile({
    @Part(name: 'files[]') required List<MultipartFile> files,
  });
}

class FilesAPI extends __FilesAPI {
  FilesAPI(Dio dio) : super(dio);

  Future<List<AppFile>> uploadFile({
    required List<MultipartFile> files,
  }) {
    return _uploadFile(
      files: files,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is okay if you want to abandon the retrofit code generation. But if you still want to keep using retrofit and dio, just import in the file that you defined the @Multipart.

```
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
```

and you still can keep content type as contentType: "application/octet-stream" as below:

```
@Part(contentType: "application/octet-stream") File file,
```

This way, the error thrown by retrofit code generation will be gone as MediaType is from http_parser library.